# Multiple Sized CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

[image]
I want to make multiple UICollectionViewCells of Various size like the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use collectionViewFlowLayout and make a function inside collectionViewFlowLayout subclass and call that function from following function to give desired size for the cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```